# obtener ultimo registro en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una base de datos en MySQL y cada tabla tiene su clave primaria que fue insertada utilizando la siguiente estructura: `"INSERT INTO TABLA VALUES (UUID(),CAMPO1,CAMPO2)"`, hasta ahí todo perfecto.

Mi duda es la siguiente, como puedo obtener la ultima inserción de dicha tabla, que lamentablemente al hacer este tipo de inserciones no hay un orden correlativo como para poder usar `last_insert_id()`, entre otros. Cabe destacar que esta es la consulta que debo realizar (ya que no es necesario obtener el ultimo registro inmediatamente haberlo insertado): `SELECT ultimo_registro FROM tabla`

PD: hay que tener en cuenta que las tablas no se pueden modificar, la db puedo tocarla pero no modificarla, y si son paginas distintas, en una donde se realiza el registro de la "nueva pyme", y en la otra donde se realiza el registro del producto que ofrece esa pyme, para hacer ese registro necesito la id de esa pyme

Espero respuestas, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo eso lo hago usando transacciones, en la transacción inicias el insert, cuando se hace consulta el ultimo id, si hay algun error con el insert la transaccion finaliza y devuelve el error

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres decir es que `UUID` no es auto_increment? ¿A qué te refieres cuando hablas de *al hacer este tipo de inserciones*?

Comment: Las bases de datos no manejan un concepto de primero o ultimo. Si no tenes una forma de distinguir el tiempo de la insercion (un autoincremental, una fecha), no hay forma de saber cual es el ultimo

Comment: A Cedano, buenos dias estimado, que al realizar una insercion con la clave primaria en UUID() y no auto_incremental, la clave primaria pasa a ser hexadecimal, por lo tanto los datos no se registran ordenadamente, a eso me refiero

Comment: Podes aclarar que podes y que no podes hacer con las tablas, (se pueden modificar? podes tocar la db?) tambien, aclara el flujo (si son paginas distintas, hay temas de concurrencia) y a que llamas el ultimo registro.. el ultimo registro de cualquier usuario? el de este usuario?

Comment: @gbianchi perdón la demora, las tablas no se pueden modificar, la db puedo tocarla pero no modificarla, y si son paginas distintas, en una donde se realiza el registro de la "nueva pyme", y en la otra donde se realiza el registro del producto que ofrece esa pyme, para hacer ese registro necesito la id de esa pyme.... pero gracias a sus comentarios y ayuda, tengo mas claro lo que puedo hacer ahora, recien no sabia como llegar a la solucion

Comment: Entonces podrias hacer un SP, que devuelva el uuid recien insertado, y pasarle esa info a la pagina siguiente? una mezcla entra la respuesta de Mario y algo mas?

Comment: @gbianchi claro eso tengo pensado hacer, al final de todos los comentarios logre sacar una idea, mas bien aclarar un poco mas lo que tenia pensado, ahora hay que ver si funciona

Comment: ok, cuando tengas una respuesta clara, ponela. Ademas, por favor, agrega la info que falta en la pregunta (todo lo que pusiste en comentario).

Comment: Patricio, si te interesa saber el último registro insertado, ¿por qué no usas un auto-incremental en tu tabla, o una columna que sirva de marca del tiempo, que marque el momento de creación de la fila?. He leído que `UUID()` no es siempre seguro.

Answer (score 2):

Pienso que la forma más directa y sencilla de hacer esto es separando la operación en dos pasos:

```
1-SELECT UUID()
2-INSERT INTO TABLA (id, CAMPO1) VALUES ($uuid, VALUE1)
```

donde `$uuid` es el valor retornado del primer paso. Luego, puedes consultar por el registro con ese id.

Comment: Estimado buenas tardes, si eso mismo pienso, el unico y gran detalle es que la insercion se hace en una pagina "pyme.php" y la consulta se realiza en otra pagina "productos.php", por eso es mi duda :)

Comment: Si se  hace en 2 páginas puede que tengas un problema con la concurrencía.

Comment: Entonces podrías definir un trigger asociado a la tabla para que se almacene en una variable de SQL el último uuid insertado, así luego sólo tendrías que recuperar el valor de esa varibale.

Comment: Suena a problemas con concurrencia esto...

Comment: a que se refieren con concurrencia?

Comment: Mira mi comentario en tu pregunta. No esta claro cual va a ser el ultimo que vas a recibir, si vas a recibirlo. @patriciomilla

Answer (score 0):

Estimados gracias por su comentarios y ayuda, la unica solucion que encontre es que cree un nuevo campo que al insertar dicha pyme de la discordia, inserta la fecha actual de la creacion de aquella, me tenia complicado el no poder modificar las tablas, pero hable con mi superiores y me dieron el visto nuevo a crear este nuevo campo. De lo contrario era imposible obtener el ultimo registro con una id en formato UUID.

gracias por su paciencia y ayuda :)

Comment: ¿Entonces obtendrás tus Ids en base a fechas? ten cuidado con los duplicados.